# What is the best encoding for buildin a multilingual java based web application, and why?

Tags: java, encoding, internationalization

Just curious about the the encoding of files (the actual rendered pages).  What encoding should they be in to support widest possible language space in a typical jsp type web application.

Answer (score 10):

The multilingual pages should be rendered in UTF-8 encoded to maximize the chances that the user's browser can display them correctly.  This is a [W3C recommendation](http://xml.coverpages.org/CharmodREC.html).

Answer (score 1):

[EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code)

Comment: Huh?  Is this an obscure joke on the OP's name?

Comment: Hah - I didn't even notice the OP's name.  Nope - this is just an obscure joke.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 supports all characters that could be used.

Comment: @Deep ... unless you want to write Klingon :-).

Comment: How can an 8 bit encoding support all character sets out there?

Comment: UTF-8 is not an 8 bit encoding. It is a variable-width encoding. Characters encoded as UTF-8 take up between 1 and 4 bytes. See examples in this table: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_javadatatypes

Comment: There are UTF-16 and UTF-32 which may use more space for the same charactor. UTF-8 is liek some kind of "Best Practice". It uses a byte to store an English charactor, two bytes to store a frequent-used multi-bytes charactor, and three bytes to store a unfrequent-used multi-bytes charactors.